# How to increase WHM Max Files Upload Limits

Tags: cpanel, whm, dedicated-server

I purchased a dedicated server and installed linux centos with cpanel. I'm able to increase file upload size limit 2gb maximum. I have 6 TB space available. This is a dedicated server purchased from OVH.com,

> - WHM, How i could increase it 10GB or more ?
> - WHM, How could i increase max files upload in one operation, Currently there are 6 files simultaneously is allowed to upload through cpanel. How could i change it?

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding version of cPanel and version of easyapache(3 or 4) configured

Comment: I'm using cpanel 11.58 with apche 4.

Answer (score 5):

Login inot WHM
Goto **Software** >> **MultiPHP INI Editor**

Select the php version from the dropdown for which you want to edit directives.

Once you make necessary changes in directive, click on **Apply**

The changes will get applied to all the websites using the php version.

If you are looking to increase connection from a single IP then goto

Service Manager >> FTP Server Configuration >> **Maximum Connections Per IP Address**. This will allow you to increase concurrent connection from a single IP.
**Maximum Connections** will show you the number of concurrent FTP connection can be made.

Hope this helps.